# Regex in mule expressionlanguage

Tags: regex, mule, mule-el

I would like to know the meaning of the regular expression used in mule expression language

I have a choice component that uses the following expression

```
regex('^[\\w\\s]+=.*',payload['Created_Package']) != null
```

Could some one please explain the meaning of the above  expression?

Comment: Have you tried yet any of the online tools ([regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zT8yN3), [regex explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2B%3D.*)...) that offer to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression first starts at the beginning of the string, hence the `^` anchor, then matches any character that is considered a word character (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`) or whitespace (`1` or more times) followed by matching an equal `=` sign. Finally matching any character except newline (`0` or more times)

Some **valid** matches would be:

```
foo=bar
123=456
   =foo
foo=&^&#$$#[]&^#
```

Some **invalid** matches would be:

```
*#*=dfds
[foo]=bar
1.2.3=456
```

A good tool that offers explanation of a regular expression, [Explain Regular Expression](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2b=.%2a&.submit=Explain!&.cgifields=mode)